# When using Dropbox to sync Keepass db, is it ok to open it in synced folder?

Tags: windows, backup, keepass, synchronization

I'm going to be storing a Keepass 2 database file (`.kdbx`) in a local folder that's synced by Dropbox. Is it safe to use Keepass to open the database directly considering everything in the folder is synced?

For example, if I have Dropbox syncing `C:\Users\Me\Dropbox` and but `passwords.kdbx` in it, if I then open `passwords` using Keepass, would temporary plaintext files get created in `C:\Users\Me\Dropbox` and synced to Dropbox that would allow someone to access to Dropbox to figure out my passwords?

I'm just switching to this system of backing up my passwords with Dropbox so any tips are appreciated. I won't be storing the key file for the db in Dropbox. I won't have Dropbox startup with the computer as I only use it for backups so will manually start it periodically (the other files, like my resume/CV, I don't care if they are stored in plaintext in the cloud).

TL;DR
Is it safe to open a Keepass2 database file that is in folder that's synced with Dropbox, or do plaintext temporary files get created that could leak information to Dropbox?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **Yes**, it is safe. KeePass does not write any plain text passwords to disk, instead it keeps the database and passwords in memory.